# DB2 Stored Procedure. How can I dynamically create a variable name inside a loop using the iteration variable?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

I'm trying to create a list of variables dependent on the result of a query. I could be creating any number of variables so I want it to be dynamic. However, I can't work out how to incorporate the loop iteration number into the variable names.

I'm thinking about something like this:

```
declare rc int default 0;
declare n_rows int;    

--The number of variables to declare below is unknown   

  select count(1) into n_row from MyTable;
  declare varname1 to varname@n_rows varchar(100);

    while rc < n_rows do    
  select varname into var@rc from (select varname, rownumber() over() as rn  from MyTable) where rn = rc;
```

-- I want this to resolve to something like:

```
select varname into var1...

select varname into var2...

select varname into var3..
```

end while;

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, if you find yourself in the situation where you have to store an unknown number of variables, it is an indication of an incorrect program design. Why do you think you need to store every row in memory? Databases are optimized for set processing.

However, if you insist on doing things your way, consider using arrays; an array can grow as you add elements to it (until it consumes all application memory and crashes the database, but that's none of your concern, right?)